# Authenticode certificate to avoid virus flagging

Tags: code-signing, antivirus, authenticode

Will an authenticode certificate stop anti-virus software from flagging my application? I've done some research and am aware that it will come up as a verified company during install, but I'm really looking for it so that A/V will stop giving false positives on my application.

Answer (score 1):

A certificate won´t stop flagging your application with the majority of AV. But...for SmartScreen worked for us at least.
I guess the best approach is to ask the vendors to put in their WhiteList, for example:

kaspersky

http://whitelist.kaspersky.com/trusted

Avast

https://www.avast.com/pt-br/faq.php?article=AVKB229

Symantec

https://submit.symantec.com/false_positive/